# Simplest implementation of Wayland standalone application

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, wayland

I am trying to make an embedded system that is basically a graphical app running on Raspberry Pi with a touchscreen. It seems that Wayland is the best choice, but the documentation for it is lacking at best and uncomprehensible, outdated and awful at worst.

Therefore I'm asking here, how does one make the most basic implementation of Wayland that will allow me to just launch a single fullscreen app and basically draw and rotate a model?

I'm already familliar with OpenGL from using WebGL, so what I need the most is the Wayland part of things.

Comment: The whole point of Wayland is getting the output of several applications on the screen at the same time. If you want to do single application fullscreen, then you don't need Wayland. KMS+GBM suffices. There's an example program called "kmscube".  I have a fork of it, but that particular one doesn't cover the latest stuff available. Ever since it should have become possible to use it even with the proprietary drivers of Nvidia and AMD, but I never tried doing that so far. https://github.com/datenwolf/kmscube

Comment: Searching for `opengl wayland client` gets me [this](https://gist.github.com/Miouyouyou/ca15af1c7f2696f66b0e013058f110b4), [this](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/41), and [this](https://jan.newmarch.name/Wayland/EGL/) in the first 5 results.

Comment: @genpfault welp, I somehow missed those keywords, searched things like "wayland application" and got bullcrap. Thank you.